# How do I pass an object data as a value (not as reference) using angularJS $broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, broadcast

I'm trying to pass some `data` and `action` within two controllers by using AngularJS $broadcast event. But I'd problems with passing the data as a value (not reference).

What I've done so far is first I created a function that broadcast `sendCartPreview` event with an object of `shoppingCart` inside shopping-cart.controller.js

```
//function inside shopping-cart.controller.js
function sendCartPreview() {
  var shoppingCart = $scope.shoppingCart;
  $rootScope.$broadcast('sendCartPreview', shoppingCart);
}
```

Then I add a listener of the event on another controller which retrieve the shoppingCart data and pass the data value to `sendCartPreview` function inside the controller

```
//function inside chat.controller.js
$scope.$on("sendCartPreview", function(event, message){
  sendCartPreview(message);
})
```

Basically the sendCartPreview function received the object data and added it to an array of message.

```
function sendCartPreview(shopping_cart) {
  //some logic here and push the data to an array
  vm.arrayOfMessage.push(shopping_cart);
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is whenever `$scope.shoppingCart` value changes, the value inside `vm.arrayOfMessage` also change according to the respective changes. What I want to achieve in the mean time is passing the data as a value (not by reference) so that everytime $scope.shoppingCart value changed, it will not affect the data inside vm.arrayOfMessage. How do I achieve that? Kindly need your help in this, any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use $rootScope.$apply() or $scope.$apply();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a deep copy call like `sendCartPreview(angular.copy(message));`

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty easy. I assume you have jquery also.

```
var cart = jQuery.extend(true, {}, shoppingCart);
```

& broadcast cart.

Comment: I think that I prefer using angular.copy instead. Anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular.copy, for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy